# Stolen Android Tablet

Tags: samsung, sim-card, lost-phone

If a tablet has been stolen, the sim card removed and been factory reset, is it possible, at all, to have it tracked?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please also see [these answered questions](/search?q=[lost-phone]+tracking+answers%3A1) on the topic.

Comment: You can contact your nearest **police station** about the theft and they can track your phone by it's **IMEI** number. Otherwise, I think there's no other way.

Answer (score 1):

If it's been factory reset, there's not much you can do. Assuming your google account or samsung account has been removed from the device, there is no way to track it.